# Getting error: non-static method getTotalPlayers() cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java

I don't see what I'm doing wrong here or how anything here is static without it being declared that way. I just need to be pointed in the right direction here.

Test code:

```
public class PaintballPlayerTest
{
//Test program for PaintballPlayer assignment

public static void main (String [] args)
{
//Part 1 check constructor & toString --(make sure ID is working too)
PaintballPlayer sheldon = new PaintballPlayer ("Sheldon", "Lee", "Cooper");
PaintballPlayer leonard = new PaintballPlayer ("Leonard", "Hofstadter");
PaintballPlayer amy = new PaintballPlayer ("Amy", "Farrah", "Fowler");

System.out.println(sheldon);
System.out.println(leonard);

//Part 2 test getTotalPlayer --should be 3
System.out.println("The team has this many players " + PaintballPlayer.getTotalPlayers());
```

My code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class PaintballPlayer
{
private String firstName, middleName, lastName;
private String secFirst, secLast;
private int id;
private int count;
private static int totalPlayers;
private int playerID;
private int players;

public PaintballPlayer(String first, String middle, String last)
{
    count = 0;
    id = totalPlayers++;
    players = count++;
    firstName = first;
    middleName = middle;
    lastName = last;
}

public PaintballPlayer(String f, String l)
{
    this (f,"",l);
    id = count++;


}


 public PaintballPlayer() 
{
totalPlayers++;
 }

 public static int getTotalPlayers() 
{
return totalPlayers;
}

public String toString()
{
    String name;
    String n;
    name = firstName + " " + middleName + " " + lastName;

    return name;

}


public int getPlayerID()
{
    playerID = count;
    return playerID;
}
  }
```

Again, my problem is with the getTotalPlayers() method.

EDIT: This is my edited code applying the fixes provided. Thank you!

Comment: There are semantic problems in your code.Why are you setting `count=0` on the constructor. And `id = count++;` and `players=count++;` ,these will increment count from 2. I suggest you to use `count++;` then `id=count;` `players = count;` and don't make `count=0;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getTotalPlayers()` is not a static method, so you need an instance of `PaintballPlayer` to call this method.

If you want to store the total players inside `PaintballPlayer`, you need an static attribute (same reference for all instances):

```
class PaintballPlayer {

  private static int totalPlayers;

  public PaintballPlayer() {
    totalPlayers++;
  }

  public static int getTotalPlayers() {
    return totalPlayers;
  }
}
```

Comment: Okay great! This works. However I'm getting that there are 0 players and there should be a total of 3. And now where the playerID was 2 when ran, it is now 4. Hmm.

Comment: see the comment on your post.

Comment: You changed the `totalPlayers` attribute to `static`?

Comment: I did. I got the playerID part fixed by removing the "players" variable altogether. I'm trying to figure out why it is returning 0 players still.

Comment: @GnomezGrave: I applied your suggestion, which brought my ID back down to 0 instead of leaving it at 2. My total players is still at 0 as well. Thank you for your help though.

Comment: make the count variable static too. and remove count++ from 2nd constructor.

Comment: Hopefully this doesn't frustrate you too much, but this didn't work either. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Works for me.`Sheldon Lee Cooper
Leonard  Hofstadter
The team has this many players 3`
check again..

Comment: Hold on everyone! It seems to have been fixed after applying the fix below this one. Thank you all very much!

Answer (score 0):

On your code there are a few problems, on the constructor #1

```
public PaintballPlayer(String first, String middle, String last)
{
    count = 0;
    players = 0;
    id = count++;
    players = count++;
    firstName = first;
    middleName = middle;
    lastName = last;
}
```

The variables players and count are being reseted while the variable count is increased two times.

And in the constructor #2 the problem is worst:

```
public PaintballPlayer(String f, String l)
{
    this (f,"",l);
    id = count++;
    players = count++;
}
```

because you are increasing the value of count two times besides the 2 times in the original constructor, so four times in total.

Once u have done what Devon Freese says u will have to modify the constructor of PaintballPlayer

```
public PaintballPlayer(String first, String middle, String last)
{
    id = totalPlayers++;
    firstName = first;
    middleName = middle;
    lastName = last;
}
```

Comment: Modifying this gives me a total of 4 players and the player id is now 2. So playerID = good and totalPlayers just needs to be 3 now.

Comment: I already have edited the post. It seems it is not reviewd yet.

Comment: im still seing the old code, i'll check the post in a few mins.

Comment: It works now. I had to change one little thing when applying this fix. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
import java.util.*;

public class PaintballPlayer {

    private String firstName, middleName, lastName;
    private String secFirst, secLast;
    private int id;
    private static int count;
    private static int totalPlayers;
    private int playerID;
    private static int players;

    public PaintballPlayer(String first, String middle, String last) {
        count++;
        id = count;
        players = count;
        firstName = first;
        middleName = middle;
        lastName = last;
    }

    public PaintballPlayer(String f, String l) {
        this(f, "", l);
        id = count;
        players = count;
    }

    public String toString() {
        String name = firstName + " " + middleName + " " + lastName;
        return name;
    }

    public static int getTotalPlayers() {
        totalPlayers = players;
        return totalPlayers;
    }

    public int getPlayerID() {
        playerID = count;
        return playerID;
    }
}

class PaintballPlayerTest {
//Test program for PaintballPlayer assignment

    public static void main(String[] args) {
//Part 1 check constructor & toString --(make sure ID is working too)
        PaintballPlayer sheldon = new PaintballPlayer("Sheldon", "Lee", "Cooper");
        PaintballPlayer leonard = new PaintballPlayer("Leonard", "Hofstadter");
        PaintballPlayer amy = new PaintballPlayer("Amy", "Farrah", "Fowler");

        System.out.println(sheldon);
        System.out.println(leonard);

//Part 2 test getTotalPlayer --should be 3
        System.out.println("The team has this many players " + PaintballPlayer.getTotalPlayers());
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry to post this as a new answer. But since the asker is confused, I've posted this.

Comment: Thanks. All of you helped me out a ton. I appreciate it.